# can common overriding code be shared

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, assert

I am new to ruby and I'm hoping someone can help me. I am writing tests using test::unit and within my tests I needed to run some code before an assert was called so I overrided the assert methods like so:

```
class TestSomething < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def assert_equal(expected, actual, message = nil)
    mycode ..
    super(expected, actual, message)
  end

  def assert(object, message)
    my code ...
    super(object, message)
  end

  def assert_not_nil(object, message = "")
    my code ...
    super(object, message)
  end

  def setup

  end

  def test_case1

  end

  def test_case1

  end

  def teardown

  end

end
```

The above structure works fine and the asserts call my code. The thing is I have 100s of test classes. The assert overriding will be the same for all of them. Do I have to copy the assert overrides to the top of every class or is there a way for all of them to get the assert overrides in one go?

One more question. Is there a way of catching an error if it occurs anywhere within the entire class?

A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you do not want to use [`before` filter](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/filters), but the question as it was stated has an answer: since ruby classes are open, one might do the following.

```
class Test::Unit::TestCase
  # store the original
  alias_method :assert_equal_original, :assert_equal
  # override
  def assert_equal *args
    # mycode ..
    assert_equal_original *args
  end
  # the same for other methods
end
```

Once it is done, any derived class will call `my_code` before calling the original method.

---

To catch an error within the scope of the class is impossible, AFAIK.

Comment: do I create a new ruby class and inherit it? Sorry about the silly question but I'm only 2 weeks coding in ruby

Comment: The code above _patches_ the `Test::Unit::TestCase` itself. After that you inherit it as you’ve done before (`class TestSomething < Test::Unit::TestCase`) and all `assert_*` methods, that you have patched, behave as you want. Think of it as you were the original author of `Test::Unit::TestCase` and you made some changes to it.

Comment: yes but where do I put the above code? sorry but that is not clear to me

Comment: E.g. in the very top of `spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: but I'm not using rspec. Thats why I don't use before as you referenced

Comment: You just need to ensure this is loaded. Create a separate file, put it there and require it from everywhere. I do not know the structure of your project, that’s why I can’t suggest anything more precise.